# Anti-Chamber timer has an hour and five minutes remaining

Tags: antichamber

When the timer runs out is it a "Game Over" sequence? 
I am wondering if I am going to lose all my progress when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer is kind of a red herring. If it runs out, you can continue playing the game as normal. However, you get an achievement if you beat the game before the timer runs out (in 90 minutes). If you don't do this the first time, you can easily restart the game and do it in a later run.

Comment: There are no achievements in Antichamber, so the second part of this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You won't lose anything after the time runs out.

> When the timer finishes the only thing that will happen is that you will unlock sign #6 which says *"Live on your own watch, not on someone else's"*